# How to get a value from firebase using firego?

Tags: go, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve values from firebase database using firego. I have found a solution on github

```
var v map[string]interface{}
if err := f.Value(&v); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", v)
```

But, I am unable to implement the above code. I have to retrieve from a child named Employee_Details. How can I do this?

Comment: change the line `var v map[string]interface{}` for `v := make(map[string]interface{})`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
    v := map[string]employeeDetails{}
    err := dB.Child("Employee_Details").Value(&v)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("%s\n", v)
```

Where Employee_Details is a child in the database and employeeDetails is a struct i used to store values.